# Get Hadoop Cluster Details

Tags: java, hadoop

I have created a pseudo cluster on a vm and I am trying to get my cluster information such as number of nodes, live node, dead etc. by using the Hadoop's API from a Java program.

Unfortunatelly, I am not able to use any of the methods of the `FSNamesystem` class. It's like I have to cluster discovery using Java client.
same information as  we get using http port 50070.

If the following statement will work I mean if I can create the object which should not return `null` then I can get all the details regarding my cluster

```
FSNamesystem f= FSNamesystem.getFSNamesystem();
```

And also how I can inject dependency for NameNode?